# POST Dictionary as JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, dictionary

I need to send some fields (from VB.Net application) in Dictionary as JSON format to web services.

Below is the code:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
 dict.Add("Drinks", "2")
 dict.Add("ID", "1")
 Dim parameters As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)
 Dim jsonString As String = "{""Pram"":""" + parameters + """}"
 Dim Uri As New Uri(String.Format("http://***/WebServices/UpdateSQL"))
 Dim data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString)
 Dim result_post As String = SendRequest(Uri, data, "application/json", "POST")
```

In my webservices(ASP.NET c#) I am trying to capture above string as in below code

```
public ActionResult UpdateSQL(string Pram)
```

I am getting error code 500: Internal server error. I tried passing individual fields from VB application and that works fine. Below is code if I send individual fields

```
Dim jsonString As String = "{""SQL"":""" + sSQL + """," &
                            """TableName"":""" + tableName + """," &
                            """Drinks"":""""2"",""ID"":""1""}"
```

The above json string when sent works absolutely fine and are captured in webservices as below code:

```
public ActionResult UpdateSQL(string SQL, string TableName, string Drinks, string ID)
```

It's only when I serialize Dictionary as string and try to send,getting Internal Server Error.
Please advise if I am missing something.Thanks

Comment: Any chance you could debug and post the full error message? Also, there is no reason to wrap the `parameters` in `"` in your `jsonString`, as it will be serialized as a full object, and in your current version it would be an object represented by a string

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks a lot. Your suggestion did the trick. By removing " at least it's hitting my web services code now. But now "null" value is being received for Pram. Below are some of the values for reference:
parameters : "{""Drinks"":""2"",""ID"":""1""}"
jsonString : "{""Pram"": {""Drinks"":""2"",""ID"":""1""}}"

In my webservices the Pram value is null somehow. Could you please advise, what could be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: That is not surprising, you are sending a json object, which would assume that you are expecting an object with a property `Pram` that contains an object with properties `SQL`, `TableName`, `Drinks` and `ID`

Comment: @Icepickle Actually I modified my webservices as below to just test for dictionary object.
public ActionResult UpdateSQL(string Pram)
Sending Dim jsonString As String = "{""Pram"":" + parameters + "}" from VB. So ideally the webservices should expect only Pram with string value in it. Checked value in my webservices and it's null.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        dict.Add("Drinks", "2")
        dict.Add("ID", "1")
        Dim parameters As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.None)
        Dim Uri As New Uri(String.Format("http://localhost:60627/home/test/"))
        Dim webClient As New WebClient()
        Dim resByte As Byte()
        Dim resString As String
        Dim reqString() As Byte
        webClient.Headers("content-type") = "application/json"
        Dim senddata As Object = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(New With {Key .param = parameters}).ToString()
        reqString = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(senddata)
        resByte = webClient.UploadData(Uri, "post", reqString)
        resString = Encoding.Default.GetString(resByte)
```

> First change this type of Concatination
>    **"{""Pram"":""" + parameters + """}**"
>    for It's Make Little confustion.

And The Data Not Sending To the Server Property Because problem is Escapse Sequence That Concat is Not Given Proper Serialization of the Data.

In Above I Change the Code For

```
Dim parameters As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.None)
```

It's Change the Data

> {"Drinks":"2","ID":"1"}

The Next Serialization It's Change the

> {"param":"{\"Drinks\":\"2\",\"ID\":\"1\"}"}

But Your Serlization of Send Data is

> {"param":"{"Drinks":"2","ID":"1"}"}

So, the Data is Not Sending Properly
[image]

I was Checked Properly it's Working Fine....

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I was struggling from last 2 days.